# Который или которого?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Совсем запуталась в предложении: Моя любимая игрушка-это заяц, который я сшила сама ИЛИ:  Моя любимая игрушка - это заяц, которого я сшила сама.Как правильно?Почему? Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

*Моя любимая игрушка — это заяц, **которого** я сшила сама.*

Здесь  В.п. совпадает с Р.п., так как игрушечный заяц условно считается **одушевленным**.

Сравнить: Моя любимая игрушка — это домик, **который** я сделала сама. Теперь В.п. совпадает с И.п., так как домик — неодушевленный.